# Adding subelement text in element constructor using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

Is it possible to pass the text attribute of an subelement in the constructor? I'll describe. I want to join the second and third lines to one line:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
son = ET.SubElement(parent, tagName) 
son.text = 'some string'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I flagged this as a duplicate of [How to set ElementTree Element text field in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093843/how-to-set-elementtree-element-text-field-in-the-constructor).

In short, no, the constructor doesn't support it. You can write a custom function though:

```
def text_element(parent, tag, text, *args, **kwargs):
    element = ET.SubElement(parent, tag, *args, **kwargs)
    element.text = text
    return element
```